# Animation jump in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I'm getting a jump on mouseout with a simple jQuery animate. An image slides up smoothly on mouseover, but on mouseout, it jumps up a few pixels before sliding down.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/g_thom/HMS2Z/1/

I don't notice the issue in Safari or Firefox (and don't have IE handy at the moment). I tried setting the height/width explicitly, and zeroing out the margin/padding, but that didn't have any effect on the jump.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because the default jQuery animation mode has a smooth speed up and slow down (called `swing` easing) - which causes a sudden stop to appear like a jump. You can tell animate to only use `linear` animation, which prevents the jump:

```
$('img').hover(function () { 
    $(this).animate( { 'top': '-10' },1000, 'linear');
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate( { 'top': '0' },1000,'linear');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HMS2Z/4/

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately, the jump is still there, but it's hard for you to advise anyway, unless you can see it.

Comment: In my version of Chrome - 12.0.742.112 (90304) running on Ubuntu, this fixed it. What version of Chrome are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I updated your example with border and new display for the image so that you can see it returns to it’s initial position on mouseout: [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/HMS2Z/2/)